# call class as function in c++

Tags: c++, class

in python you can define a class A

```
class A(object):
    .....

    def __call__(self, bar):
        #do stuff with bar
        ....
```

which allows me to use it like this:

```
bar = "something"
foo = A()
foo(bar)
```

I would like to do the same thing in c++, but I did not find anything, Is this possible or did I overlook something?

Comment: I do not understand your example. What is the purpose of assigning `foo`? You don't do anything with it. Please explain what you are trying to accomplish *in words*. For example, "construct an `A` from a string."

Comment: Learn about *operator overloading in C++*. Overloading `operator()` might be of most interest to you.

Comment: You want a [function object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B)

Answer (score 1):

The name of the class is reserved in C++ for constructors. You can create a constructor with parameters of the type you need, but it will always be creating a new instance of the class.
If you need to perform some task that is not instantiating the class, create a method using a different name.

```
class A {
    ...
public:
    A(); // Constructor with no parameters
    A(BarType bar); // Constructor with parameter BarType
    void someMethod(BarType bar); // Method that takes bar and performs some operation
}
```

Usage:

```
BarType bar = BarType();
A aInstance = A(bar);
```

To perform some task without instantiating with parameters:

```
A aInstance = A();
BarType bar = BarType();
aInstance.someMethod(bar);
```

Comment: Not an answer: Question author stated desired behaviour and illustrated how you would do it in Python. This post does not answer his question.

Comment: @rev Actually, he didn't. Your edit *completely* changed the question.

Comment: @CodyGray Question title, text and context of code (defining `__call__`) clearly state author intent. Edit was about obvious typo.

Comment: sorry for typo, Revolver_Ocelot is right